# Looping array - Jumping from last to first and vice versa?

Tags: c#, java, c++

I have an array called message. I move to its next index when a user enters "next". Similarly, for previous. I want to be able to move to next and previous in a simple way. 
I know a simple way for next but not previous. How do I do it ?

```
array[] message  = {"Hello", "good", "people", "!"};//index starts at 0
int currentIndex = 0;
int next = 2;//an option which can be used in an if or switch-case
int previous = 1;
```

For going to the next element -

```
moveNext(){
int currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % message.length;
}

//Any neat trick, similar to the one for moveNext() ? 
movePrevious(){
//Yes, you can use an if-else check here, but I am trying to avoid that.
}
```

**Edit -**

```
Example - Array is of LENGTH = 5, that is indexes 0 to 4. 
When currentIndex = 4 and you enter next, then set currentIndex = 0
When currentIndex = 0 and you enter previous, then set currentIndex = 4
```

Comment: @AntP He wants it to wrap around

Comment: @AntP - what if the currentIndex = 0. Then, we get an outOfBoundsException. I am trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can still use your one-line remainder technique if you add `message.length`:

```
int currentIndex = (currentIndex + message.length - 1) % message.length;
```

It's only more helpful for index 0, but it seems to be what you're looking for. Do take care that adding introduces the possibility of overflow with a large length.

Sample code to show the logic:

```
public class Looper {

    static int len = 4;
    static int currentIndex = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Index = " + currentIndex);
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            movePrev();
        }

    }// main

    public static void movePrev(){
        currentIndex = (currentIndex + len - 1) % len;
        System.out.println("Moved prev. Index = " + currentIndex);
    }

}// Looper
```

Output:

> Index = 0
>   Moved prev. Index = 3
>   Moved prev. Index = 2
>   Moved prev. Index = 1
>   Moved prev. Index = 0
>   Moved prev. Index = 3

Comment: `%` is not the modulus operator, it is the remainder operator.  If it performed a modulus it would work as is.

Answer (score 2):

What you really want is to have a modulus operation, rather than a remainder operator ([What's the difference?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/05/what-s-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus.aspx)).  That will have the desired semantics for dealing with negative dividends.  Fortunately, getting one from the other isn't too hard:

```
public static int Modulus(int dividend, int divisor)
{
    return (dividend % divisor + dividend) % divisor;
}
```

You can now write:

```
int currentIndex = Modulus(currentIndex + 1, message.length);
```

or

```
int currentIndex = Modulus(currentIndex - 1, message.length);
```

Comment: @Jarod42 Right, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
//moveNext()

    if ( Length != 0 && ++currentIndex == Length ) currentIndex = 0;


//movePrevious

    if ( Length != 0 && currentIndex-- == 0 ) currentIndex = Length - 1;
```

Comment: Previet ! But, that is not what I am looking for. Please see the question again.

Comment: It's probably an assignment of some type where he is limited from if statement.

Comment: @DoubleDouble - actually no. In my android book, Big Nerd Ranch Guide, I saw the code for moving to next. Wondering if i could do something similar for previous.

Comment: `Yes, you can use an if-else check here, but I am trying to avoid that.`  This doesn't avoid that...